# Browse and post a path not the file

Tags: html, file-upload

I've got a slightly unusual scenario. A web app running on a local network can perform various operations on any file on the network it can access. At present the user copies/pastes the UNC path to the file into a text input and clicks submit.

The server retrieves the file, performs some operations and returns the results to the user.

I'd like to allow the user to browse for the file using the webpage - but I don't want to upload the file, just get the full path to it. Is this possible?

I'm aware there will be a couple of scenarios which are doomed to failure - eg browsing to a local path not a UNC share but I can cover this with some validation. There will also be scenarios when the server can access a path the user can't (this is intentional) so browsing wouldn't work here.

All users will be techies who should get the point. Of course, if there were a way to limit the browse dialog to a UNC path, that would be even better but I suspect it's impossible.

Note, we already limit support to the latest versions of the main browsers and since this is just a utility feature, limited support is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that can't be done. It's a security feature.